# Is this equation wrong?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I have a trouble in understanding one of the current equation in the following example:

https://www.circuitlab.com/textbook/dependent-source-feedback/

To me

i3 = (Va - Vb)/R2 which yields:

Va - Vb = 10*i3

But the example says:

Vb - Va = 10*i3

Am I wrong or the example?

Comment: This notation \$\frac{V_A - V_B}{R_2}\$ assumes that the voltage at point \$A\$ is greater than the voltage at point \$B\$. 

Therefore, the current is flowing from point \$A\$ to\$B\$.  But on a page, the \$I_3\$ current is flowing from point \$B\$ to point \$A\$ and this is why \$\frac{V_B - V_A}{R_2}\$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that current, in the conventional way, flows from positive to negative, which means the current flows from the greater voltage to a lower one.

In this case, \$I_3\$ flows downwards, from \$V_B\$ to \$V_A\$, which means \$V_B\$ is thought to be greater than \$V_A\$ although in the end of the circuit´s resolution you´ll find that it may not be true. Then \$I_3\$ it´s supposed to be \$\frac{V_A-V_B}{R_2}\$. Anyway, for writing the equations, the link you provided brings a correct reasoning.